# Python: '{:,}'.format() why is this working?

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

There is a kata in codewars where the task is to write a function that takes an integer in input and outputs a string with currency format. For example `123456` -> `"123,456"`.

I had a solution, but it was much uglier than this one with string formatting:

```
def to_currency(price):
  return '{:,}'.format(price)
```

I've read the documentation, but I still don't know how is this working exactly?

Comment: See [PEP 378](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0378/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use python's format language like:

```
'{name:format}'.format(...)
```

`name` is optional, and can be empty:

```
'{:format}'.format(...)
```

`format` is a format specifier. If it's not given, it's usually inferred from the type of the argument given to `format(...)`.

In this case, `format` is `,`, which instructs python to add group dividers, like demanded.
From https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec :

> The `,` option signals the use of a comma for a thousands separator.
>   For a locale aware separator, use the `n` integer presentation type
>   instead.

Answer (score 6):

The [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) states that `:` introduces the format specifier, [which is defined as follows](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec):

```
format_spec ::=  [[fill]align][sign][#][0][width][,][.precision][type]
```

where all the elements are optional, and where

> The '`,`' option signals the use of a comma for a thousands separator. For a locale aware separator, use the '`n`' integer presentation type instead.

Comment: I like your answer better than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec):

> Using the comma as a thousands separator:
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> '{:,}'.format(1234567890)
> '1,234,567,890'
> ```

**Explanation**

The `:` introduces a format specifier.

The `,` format specifier signals the use of a comma for a thousands separator. It was added in Python versions 2.7 and 3.1 and it's described in more detail in [PEP 0378](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0378/).